# How can I shorten a string and later get back the original contents?

Tags: string, url

I have a really long string that I need to pass in a URL, say 10,000 characters.  Anyone know a good way to shorten it to under 2,000 chars, and then on a server somehow get the original back?

This is Objective-C talking to Ruby, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: I'm not sure the merits of sending a 10k character URL, but if there is a way to turn 10k characters into < 2k that can be translated back to the original 10k I'd like to know as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you post the data?
If you use GET the max length of a url is around 4000 characters. If you POST it you have no constraints (except timeouts memory etc)

[This article](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.19/19.04/CocoaApplications/index.html) talks about doing a post from objective-c

Comment: +1 for not answering the question, but rather giving a solution to the (likely) real problem

Comment: wow, i'm a little slow this morning.  of course.  thanks for the quick reply.

so this trigger an interesting thought process.  without using a db, does anyone know a two-way function that can shrink a string and then get it back?

Comment: If you do a POST, You can always enable HTTP compression. That will transparently compress the whole connection so it happens faster.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have to pass it in as a URL? Maybe POST-Data or Session would be more appropriate? otherwise you could store the string in a database and return the key of the inserted record as a URL Parameter. If this is a security concern (as people can just change the number if it is an integer key), you could create a UUID as key.

Answer (score 1):

Store it in a database and then just pass the id of the string in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running it through [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). If the string is guaranteed to have only a subset of possible characters -- for example, [a-zA-Z0-9] -- it can be shortened even more by converting these to unique ordinals and using a higher base encoding.

But it would probably be easier to just use POST.

Answer (score 0):

Well, compress it and [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode the result. If the string has a very specific format, a custom encoding could even yield a better compression. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Daniel: Depending on the compressibility of the data he could end up with a longer string than he started with. Also there is no guarantee he will get the 5:1 compression he needs to accomplish the task as described.

Comment: That is why I asked for an example... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would persist this information to a database (or any other persistence source) and then pass a reference to it in the URL.

Both source and destination will require access to the database, but that isn't an issue most of the time.